# O que é Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Pelo que entendi o Android NDK é voltado ao desenvolvimento com [c](/questions/tagged/c) ou [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), apesar de suportar Java através do [*JNI* (Java Native Interface)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/), todavia gostaria de entender algumas coisas:

- Quando compilamos ele se torna um executável realmente ou ele é convertido para para "maquina Java" (eu não sei se esta é a maneira correta de se referir)?
- Se ele é uma aplicação independente da "maquina java" então isto significa que as funcionalidades nativas dos aplicativos são independente do Java agora?
- A partir de que API posso usar o NDK?
- Como isto irá tratar a diferença entre processadores *ARM* e *Intel x86*? O aplicativos serão compilados no momento da instalação no dispositivo?

Comment: Guilherme: ocultei a resposta temporariamente porque encontrei 2 documentações da google que respondiam sua pergunta de formas diferentes. Vou pesquisar pouco mais e perguntar no forum da google por qual devemos no basear.

Answer (score 29):

Bom vamos lá, eu utilizo muito o ***Native Development Kit - NDK***, podemos dizer que o `JAVA` permite que você escreva ou re-utilize códigos `C` ou `C++`, mas como isso realmente funciona ?

Imagine chamar qualquer função escrita em `C` dentro da sua aplicação `java`, isso é uma mão na roda por N motivos, você pode ganhar performance, pode utilizar códigos ou bibliotecas escritas em C/C++, ou simplesmente dificultar que alguém veja o seu código, lembrando que isso não é algo exclusivo do `java`, outras linguagens também possuem essa capacidade, para que isso seja possível é preciso ter uma interface que faça a comunicação entre seu código `C` e o `java`, é neste ponto que entra o **JNI - Java Native Interface** ele será o responsável por linkar suas funções, neste ponto você vai criar funções em `Java` chamando as Funções do seu código nativo...

Respondendo suas perguntas uma a uma:

> Quando compilamos ele se torna um executável realmente ou ele é
>   convertido para para "maquina Java" (eu não sei se esta é a maneira
>   correta de se referir)?

R: Quando você compila uma aplicação java que faz uso de um código C/C++, no exato momento da compilação ao gerar o seu `.apk` você vai estar criando um `shared object` o famoso `.so` bastante comum quando você quer compartilhar funções entre outros programas em `C`, não é um executável, neste caso você vai estar criando uma biblioteca compartilhada que vai posteriormente ser chamada pelo seu código java `(System.loadLibrary)`.

> Se ele é uma aplicação independente da "maquina java" então isto
>   significa que as funcionalidades nativas dos aplicativos são
>   independente do Java agora?

R: Sim ele é independente,  se ao compilar você setou a arquitetura `x86` por exemplo, então você pode simplesmente copiar esse `.so` para um PC e chamar qualquer função existente a partir de qualquer outra linguagem que leia essa biblioteca, lembre-se, o que faz você se comunicar com a sua aplicação C no JAVA é o `JNI`...

> A partir de que API posso usar o NDK?

R: `API 3`, ou seja tem suporte desde o `Android 1.5`

> Como isto irá tratar a diferença entre processadores ARM e Intel x86?
>   O aplicativos serão compilados no momento da instalação no
>   dispositivo?

R: Você define quais serão as arquiteturas que e o NDK irá criar durante a compilação do seu `.apk`, neste momento o seu aplicativo java irá conter todos os `.so's` ou seja um para cada arquitetura definida por você, eles estarão embarcados dentro do seu apk na pasta `lib`, veja um exemplo do meu .apk, eu defini que fosse criado para todas as arquiteturas, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro de cada pasta dessa vai existir um `.so` específico para cada arquitetura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento que você executar esse aplicativo no `android` ele irá identificar qual é a arquitetura usada e irá carregar o `.so` na pasta correspondente.

***EDIT***

Gostaria de fazer mais algumas considerações, o método mostrado acima utiliza biblioteca compartilhada `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`, este parâmetro deve ser definido dentro `Android.mk`

Existe como criar um `executável`, para tal você deve substituir seu `Android.mk` para `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`, funciona de maneira parecida, só que neste caso ao compilar seu app, novas pastas são criadas contendo um binário executável referente a cada arquitetura compilada pelo `NDK`, mas agora você vai ter que tratar as arquiteturas dentro do seu código para achar o arquivo/pasta corretamente, como exemplo, eu utilizo algo assim:

```
private String getCFileName(CPUArchitecture architecture){
        final String CFileName;
        switch (architecture){
            case X86:
                String CFileName = "x86_ederwander";
                break;
            case ARMEABI_V7A:
                CFileName = "armeabi-v7a_ederwander";
                break;
            case ARMEABI_V7A_NEON:
                CFileName = "armeabi-v7a-neon_ederwander";
                break;
            default:
                CFileName = null;
                String message= "Could not determine your processor architecture correctly";
                Log.e(TAG,message);
                throw new Error(message);
        }
        return CFileName;
```

No momento da execução do seu apk ele irá definir qual binário com arquitetura correta utilizar, com a correta seleção do arquivo você pode executa-lo, se tiver algum argumento você pode passar como parâmetro também, geralmente uso algo assim:

```
    int executeCommandLine(String commandLine)
{
     try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);            

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            int read;

            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            reader.close();

            process.waitFor();

            Log.d("executeCommandLine", output.toString());

            return process.exitValue();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to execute '"+commandLine+"'", e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to execute '"+commandLine+"'", e);
        }
```

Cada caso é um caso, existem prós e contras, eu não gosto muito de criar binários, dá um trabalho gigantesco, você tem que se preocupar em achar a arquitetura correta, você tem que construir uma função no seu código java para copiar esses binários para uma pasta dentro do seu apk que tenha permissão de executar esse binário, mas como eu disse tudo depende do seu projeto, em alguns casos você não vai ter escolha e criar um binário será a alternativa, lembrando que os binários compilados, se você tiver compilado algum para arquitetura `x86` por exemplo, se você copiar esse binário para um `linux-x86`, você vai literalmente rodar/executar com um `./bincompilado-via-NDK`, portanto neste caso você não vai mais precisar do `JNI`, não existe mais interface, você está chamando realmente um código binário compilado...

Por experiencia eu te garanto que o desenvolvimento e muitos dos APPs que conhecemos hoje para Android não seriam muita coisa sem a existência do `NDK`, claro ele não é algo trivial e por isso só usamos quando for realmente necessário, geralmente em casos específicos, você não vai precisar disso se for criar algo que não demande poder total de processamento, mas a sua existência abriu as portas para que diversos aplicativos ganhassem a performance de um código nativo, hoje com a evolução constante dos processadores `ARM` ganhando cada vez mais poder de processamento, temos em nossos celulares uma gama de APP's fazendo coisas incríveis em tempo real, sem gargalos, sem latências, eu trabalho com processamento de áudio, meus aplicativos precisam de processamento extremo, algo que o Java não dá conta de suprir, o mesmo acontece para processamento de imagens em tempo real e jogos, estes aplicativos não seriam os mesmos se tudo fosse escrito somente em java, com certeza iríamos sofrer para fazer o java dar conta ou teríamos que estar anos luz a frente na arquitetura `ARM`...

Comment: Nossa só de ler por cima já deu pra ver que esta excelente! Vou ler mais e acompanhar e testar. Parabéns pelo esforço, já lhe deixo o +1, ainda vou ler e ver todos pontos, mas desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 9):

O **Android NDK** é um conjunto de ferramentas que permite implementar partes do aplicativo usando linguagens de código nativo, tais como C e C ++. Para determinados tipos de aplicativos isso pode ajudá-lo a reutilizar bibliotecas de código escritas nessas linguagens. Ou seja, nós não precisamos reinventar a roda se já existem boas bibliotecas em C ou C++.

**Exemplo**: Temos usado muito o **Android NDK** para integrar o [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) a um projeto de audio e vídeo player e streaming ao vivo para Android.

As bibliotecas escritas em C ou C++ são compiladas nativamente para serem usadas através de invocações em Java. Você pode usar o **Android NDK** em qualquer classe do seu projeto, através das **APIs** nativas do Android.

Sim, os arquivos são compilados no momento de instalação do aplicativo. Porém depois de já compilados estarão acessíveis rapidamente.

Para lhe dar mais detalhes sobre como usar o **Android NDK** precisaríamos saber mais sobre o seu projeto em específico. Portanto, fique à vontade para postar algum código ou fazer perguntas mais específicas e, assim, poderemos ajudá-lo de forma mais específica.

Comment: Compilado na instalação do aplicativo? Tem alguma referência que fala disso?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não é compilado no momento da instalação, acredito que o Winston tenha se enganado, as bibliotecas C/C++ são criadas quando você compila o seu código java,  depois no momento da execução do seu aplicativo java as bibliotecas são carregadas acessando suas funções escritas em C ...

Comment: @ederwander pelo visto foi uma confusão com o AoT, que é sobre o dex gerado, não sobre a parte nativa