# Criar um aplicativo para Android usando apenas C ou C++

Tags: android

É possível criar um aplicativo para *Android* usando apenas *C* ou *C++* sem usar *Java*? Se sim por onde posso começar e qual o nome do programa que posso utilizar?

Comment: embora concorde com a marcação de duplicação do amigo @bigown, vou comentar a pergunta a titulo de reposta, é possível sim, pra isso voce poderia usar QT, com essa ferramenta voce pode criar um app multiplataforma com C/C++ ou QML, de uma olhada em https://www1.qt.io/developers/.

Comment: Para complementar, aqui tem uma otima explicação sobre o NDK: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209598/3635