# Xamarin gera códigos fonte Java?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

Li que com o Xamarin é possível programar em C# por exemplo, e gerar uma aplicação nativa Android e IOS.

Depois de programar em C#, ele gera os fontes em Java? Eu posso depois de fazer a primeira versão do App, abandonar o C# e continuar com Java?

Sei que dessa forma eu teria alguns prós e contras, porém quero saber para ter mais informações.

Comment: Creio que o nativo não é Java, quando se refere a nativo é que ele acessa as APIs nativas do sistema operacional android que geram as janelas, listas e afins. Mas não posso afirmar porque não conheço Xamarin.

Comment: Muito boa a pergunta. Eu acho que gera código Java sim, mas provavelmente compilado.. Mesmo se não for compilado, deve ser código estranho... Feito por máquina né?! `String s1 = ""; List<Pessoa> lp;`

Comment: Quando se refere à nativo, diz-se que é compilado diretamente para bytecode para rodar na VM do sistema (ART, se não me falha a memória). Ele não gera fontes Java, gera apenas o "segundo passo".

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Não, ele usa sua própria infraestrutura e apenas se comunica com os códigos Java onde há necessidade de integração com o sistema operacional, se não me engano eles usam o [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/) para isto.

Então não pode fazer em C# e depois converter e usar o código Java.

Até é possível algum conversor de código fonte que tem por aí, mas o resultado é péssimo, então faça na linguagem que vai usar, seja C#, Java, [Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101), [C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164171/101) ou outra.